# How to exclude files in Git while disregarding .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-plumbing

## Background

I'm migrating a VCS to git. This is done by checking out from the old VCS (TFSVC) and checking into a git repository via scripts.

Essentially in such a loop:

```sh
for x in $(seq 1 100)
do
  tf get $x  # get version x
  git add .  # add everything to index
  git commit # commit
done
```

## Problem

The old VCS contains a `.gitignore`, as a part of the migration process, I don't want these patterns to apply. This can easily be fixed using `git add . --force`. The problem is that there are still things that I may want to ignore.

## What I've tried

I was hoping to use `.git/info/exclude` for the purpose, but `git-add --force` apparently ignores this in addition to `.gitignore` rules. It seems the same goes for `core.excludesFile`.

## Ideal solution

- Exclude the rules of `.gitignore`
- Use the rules in `.git/info/exclude` or some other exclude file or pattern
- Somewhat performant, the process is slow enough as it is
- Doesn't rely on modifying the working tree

An option is of-course to simply `git restore --staged $EXCLUDE_PATH_SPEC` after adding everything to the index but I'm wondering if there isn't a better solution.

I seem to recall seeing an option for specifying an ignore/exclude glob but I can't seem to be able to find it.

Maybe there's a way to achieve this using a plumbing commands, like `git update-index`?

---

Edit

I've added clarification that I'd rather not rely on a solution that modifies the working tree (ie: moving/modifying `.gitignore`) since it's been suggested multiple times. Mainly because of these reasons:

1. There are nested `.gitignore` files
2. Their existence and contents rely on the state of the other VCS, I want to be in full control
3. There is another VCS tracking the files and so anything modifying the working tree, besides the incremental fetching from the other VCS complicates matters
4. It's in all likelihood slower (although maybe not slow enough to be a major concern)

Comment: Couldn't you just do `cp /path/to/my/ignore/file .gitignore` after the `tf get` step?

Comment: @Thomas that modifies the working tree, I'd rather avoid such a solution

Comment: @CervEd There is no way to ignore `.gitignore`

Comment: Look for some sort of migration software; if none exist, consider trying your hand at your own. Use `git fast-import` to create commits. This is a usually a big job though.

Comment: @phd, yes there is `git add --force`

Comment: @torek, thanks for the advice but scripting works well enough

Comment: @CervEd Ok, there is no way to ignore only `.gitignore` but not all other exclude/ignore files.

Comment: @phd, sorry but I'm not sure I understand what you're hoping to add with your comments

Comment: @CervEd I hope you'd get that overwriting `.gitignore` is the simplest and the most reliable solution.

Comment: @phd that would be a solution, however, in this use case I obviously really want to avoid making modifications to the working tree

Comment: @CervEd By using `.git/info/exclude` you don't include everything from TFSVC anyway so I don't understand your desire to preserve `.gitignore` at all cost.

Comment: @phd because I'm dealing with two version control systems, which share the same working directory, and so I'd like to avoid making changes to the working directory and avoid the headaches that come with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the standard conveniences aren't what you want, make your own with core commands. `git ls-files` lets you build your exclusions as you like, and `git update-index` will take anything you want.

```
git ls-files -ocX /path/to/my/excludes \
| git update-index --add --remove --stdin
```

`git ls-files`

- [`-o --others`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---others) Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output
- [`-c --cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt---cached) Show cached files in the output
- [`-X --exclude-from`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--Xltfilegt) Read exclude patterns from , 1 per line.

`git update-index`

- [`--add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---add) If a specified file isn’t in the index already then it’s added.
- [`--remove`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---remove) If a specified file is in the index but is missing then it’s removed.
- [`--stdin`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#Documentation/git-update-index.txt---stdin) Instead of taking list of paths from the command line, read list of paths from the standard input

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I suggested an edit with links to the docs of the options as well as short explanations of what they do, hope you don't mind

Answer (score 1):

What about *temporary* removing `.gitignore`?

```
for x in $(seq 1 100)
do
  tf get $x
  mv .gitignore /tmp/
  git add .
  mv /tmp/.gitignore .
  git add .gitignore
  git commit -m commit$x
done
```

Comment: I think you mean to propose to temporarily replace the `.gitignore`, no?

Comment: @CervEd That's possible if you need it. And you still can use `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: okay I see now, your proposed solution is to move the `.gitignore` so that only the rules in `.git/info/exclude` and `core.excludeFile` would be used. That could work in some scenarios, but like I said, I'd really like to avoid making changes to the working tree.

Comment: @CervEd The code restores `.gitignore`. Even add it — just in case.

Comment: right I know that, but in my case there are **two** VCS here that share the same working directory. You're forgetting about the other one. Like I've said, many times, this is a route I want to avoid

Comment: @CervEd I don't see how it's relevant. After the 2nd `mv` the worktree is restored to its exact state so `tf` doesn't see any difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231987/discussion-between-cerved-and-phd).

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I've come up with is probably using `xargs` and `:!` exclude paths.

```sh
grep --invert-match '^#' < .git/info/exclude |\
 sed 's/^/:!/' |\
 xargs git add --all --force --
```

It'll probably work fine enough for my use case but I'm not sure it's the best solution. I don't know how it's going to handle complicated rules, when `xargs` is going to blow up `git add` etc. Hoping someone else can come up with a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to ignore few file in git you can do below commands-

```
git rm -r --cached  .
git  add  .
git  commit  -m  ".gitignore is now working"
```

[click here for details](http://www.jhaji.in/2016/03/add-files-to-gitignore.html)

Comment: This doesn't ignore files, this deletes everything in the index.

Comment: it looks like deleted but in actually it re-add and .gitignore will start working,I did this many times